# Pluralize a string

Tags: c++, strings

I find that a common pattern when outputting a message is the need to pluralize a word. For example, if I need to output a count of files found I would need to write something like

```
std::cout << "Found " << count << " " << (count == 1 ? "file" : "files");
```

in order to use the correct singular or plural form of "file" without resorting to a generic use of the string `"file(s)"` for any value of `count`.

To cut down a bit on the verbosity of this code (and to practice writing string-manipulation code) I developed a function which pluralizes the singular form of a word (string) if it is attached to a number not equal to 1 (one would use the plural form if the number is 0 -- as in "0 files" or even if it is not an integer -- as in "0.2 things"). Since some words have unusual pluralization rules the function accepts additional arguments for the plural form's suffix as well as any part of the singular form which is removed -- these additional arguments have default values which correspond to the usual pluralization rule to simply add an "s" to the singular form.

Here is the function along with its documentation, and a small example program to run it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/** \brief Pluralizes a string if the given quantity is not equal to exactly 1.

\tparam number an arithmetic type
\param[in] n the quantity of the string to possibly pluralize. The singular form is used if the quantity
is equal to exactly 1, otherwise the plural form is used. The plural form is used if the quantity is a
decimal that is not equal to 1 (e.g. 1.1), 0, negative (including -1), etc.
\param[in] singular the singular form of the string.
\param[in] plural_suffix the suffix string which is appended to the root of the plural form.
\param[in] replaced_root the characters at the end of the singular form which are removed/replaced to form
the root of the plural form.
\return `singular` if `n == 1`, otherwise `replaced_root` is removed from the end of the `singular` and `plural_suffix` is appended to that.
For example:
\li `pluralize(1, "test")` returns `"test"`
\li `pluralize(2, "test")` returns `"tests"`
\li `pluralize(2, "ox", "en")` returns `"oxen"`
\li `pluralize(2, "story", "ies", "y")` returns `"stories"`
\li `pluralize(2, "life", "ves", "fe")` returns `"lives"`
\li `pluralize(2, "mouse", "ice", "ouse")` returns `"mice"`
\li `pluralize(2, "sheep", "")` returns `"sheep"`
\li `pluralize(2, "he", "they", "he")` returns `"they"`
*/
template<typename number>
std::string pluralize(number n, const std::string& singular, const std::string& plural_suffix = "s", const std::string& replaced_root = "") {
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    
    if (n == number{1}) return singular;

    auto plural_root = ""s;

    const auto singular_size = singular.size();
    const auto replaced_root_size = replaced_root.size();

    // If replaced_root is an empty string then the singular form is the same as the plural root
    // replaced_root_size > singular_size should never be true, but fall back on singular as the plural root
    if (replaced_root_size == 0 || replaced_root_size > singular_size) {
        plural_root = singular;
    } else {
        // Index of the first character of the root replacement section
        // Cannot be less than 0 because singular.size() >= replaced_root.size()
        // Cannot be greater than singular.size() -- i.e. past singular.end() -- because replaced_root.size() >= 0
        const auto index = singular_size - replaced_root_size;

        // Iterators of interest
        const auto singular_begin = singular.begin();
        const auto iter = singular_begin + index;

        // The last replaced_root.size() characters of singular must match replaced_root
        // If there is no match just use the singular form as the plural root
        if (std::string{iter, singular.end()} == replaced_root) {
            plural_root = {singular_begin, iter};
        } else {
            plural_root = singular;
        }
    }

    return plural_root + plural_suffix;
}

int main() {
    int count = 2;
    
    std::cout << "Found " << count << " " << pluralize(count, "file");
}
```

I've also tested it using the following Google Test code, which passes all test cases:

```
TEST(Strings, Pluralize) {
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(1, "test"s), "test"s);
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(2, "test"s), "tests"s);
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(0, "ox"s, "en"s), "oxen"s);
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(1.1, "story"s, "ies"s, "y"s), "stories"s);
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(-1.0, "life"s, "ves"s, "fe"s), "lives"s);
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(-0.9, "mouse"s, "ice"s, "ouse"s), "mice"s);
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(-2, "sheep"s, ""s), "sheep"s);
    EXPECT_EQ(pluralize(-2.5, "he"s, "they"s, "he"s), "they"s);
}
```

Any suggestions to improve this code (naming, comments, efficiency, style, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I don't understand why we need the root replacement stuff at all. Couldn't we just pass the full singular and plural words to the function? ... Which would simply become:

```
template<class N>
std::string pluralize(N n, std::string const& singular, std::string const& plural) {
    return n == N{ 1 } ? singular : plural;
}
```

We could perhaps provide an overloaded version that takes only a single argument, and adds "s" to save typing for simple plurals.

---

I don't think the "alias" variables really help in this case. It's as easy to type `singular.size()` as it is to type `singular_size`. It's also clearer, since we don't have to then check a variable declaration to see that `singular_size` is really just `singular.size()`.

---

```
if (replaced_root_size == 0 || replaced_root_size > singular_size) {
    plural_root = singular;
```

We've done all the work we need to for this branch of execution, so we should just return from the function here. Then we don't need the `plural_root` variable yet, and we don't need to indent code into the `else` clause afterwards.

---

```
    // Cannot be less than 0 because singular.size() >= replaced_root.size()
    // Cannot be greater than singular.size() -- i.e. past singular.end() -- because replaced_root.size() >= 0
```

We should make these `assert`ions, not comments.

---

It might be clearer to use `singular.substr(...)` rather than constructing a new string out of iterators.

---

```
// The last replaced_root.size() characters of singular must match replaced_root
// If there is no match just use the singular form as the plural root
if (std::string{iter, singular.end()} == replaced_root)
```

I'm not fond of silently failing here. If the user of the function is calling it incorrectly, they would probably want to know about that (perhaps we should throw an error?)

Note that `std::string` has an `ends_with()` function in C++20.

---

As mentioned above, I'd just supply the full plural word.

However, here's what I'd probably do with the code if the method were kept the same.

```
template<typename number>
std::string pluralize(number n, const std::string& singular, const std::string& plural_suffix = "s", const std::string& replaced_root = "") {

    if (n == number{ 1 })
        return singular;

    if (replaced_root.empty())
        return singular + plural_suffix;

    if (!singular.ends_with(replaced_root)) // C++ 20
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid root replacement.");

    auto const plural_root = singular.substr(0, singular.size() - replaced_root.size());

    return plural_root + plural_suffix;
}
```

(not actually compiled / tested).

Comment: I thought about just passing the singular and plural forms as arguments, but that doesn't shorten the code for the function calls. An overload to simply append "s" helps, but there are enough cases where the rule is to append "es" or replace a final "y" with "ies" that you'd end up using the full form quite often. Otherwise, good points. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a replacement for @user673679’s answer; I think that answer stands on its own and is pretty much complete. I really just wanted to add one note not about the implementation, but about the idea: a design review rather than a code review.

But before that….

## A short, focused code review digression

I have to say I really don’t see the point in templating the *number* and not the strings. There doesn’t seem to be any sensible reason for multiple overloads of this function for different number types. On the contrary, it seems rather wasteful to have a half-dozen or more instantiations for `int`, `unsigned int`, `short`, `long`, `unsigned long long`, and so on. I see you using it with `int`s and `double`s… but (and this will come up in the design review section references) this kind of transformation almost never makes sense for fractional numbers, or for negative numbers for that matter. I’d just take `unsigned long long` and be done with it.

If I *were* to template anything, it would be the strings. Maybe something like:

```
template <typename CharT, typename Traits>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto pluralize(
    unsigned long long n,
    std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> singular,
    std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> plural)
        -> std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>
{
    return (n == 1) ? singular : plural;
}
```

That way you could use wide-character strings or Unicode (`char32_t`) strings if you please. (I’ll leave it as an exercise for the reader to make that work nicely with C-strings.)

Note also the use of string views, to avoid unnecessary construction and copying of strings. All of your test cases are wasteful. Every one constructs ***FIVE*** strings: three for the function parameters, one for `plural_root`, and one for the return value. Even @user673679’s improved versions construct 3 or 4. But if you follow their advice and refactor the function interface, and switch to string views, you can get it down to ***ZERO*** constructed strings in many cases.

Honestly, though, I wouldn’t template this function at all. I’d use `unsigned long long` and `std::string_view`, and simply state that all inputs and outputs are UTF-8 encoded (maybe *maybe* I might consider `u8string_view`, possibly only as an overload), and that’s that.

## Design review

You have identified a classic problem in user-interface programming. Unfortunately, you have not thought the problem all the way through.

Your simple example is… okay-ish:

```
std::cout << "Found " << count << " " << (count == 1 ? "file" : "files");
```

But what if the message you need to print is even *slightly* more complex? For example, suppose you wanted to say: “There are *N* files that match the search criteria.” (Hypothetically. I know you could simplify *that* message, but let’s imagine it represents something you can’t really simplify without introducing vagueness or ambiguity.) What would the code for that look like?

```
std::cout << "There " << pluralize(count, "is", "are") << ' ' << count << ' ' << pluralize(count, "file", "files") << " that " << pluralize(count, "matches", "match") << " the search criteria.";
```

Yikes. And it only goes downhill from there as the messages you display get more complex. And we haven’t even *begun* to talk about internationalization yet (but we’ll get there!).

There’s another issue this causes. Suppose I’m a user of your program. While using it, I get a message—an error message or an unexpected message—and I want to know what the hell is going on. So I do the logical thing: I search your program’s sources for the message “There are *N* files that match the search criteria.” or some variant of it (like just “match the search criteria”). And what do I find? Nothing. Because that particular string isn’t in the source code, it’s constructed on the fly instead. That’s be no help for me whatsoever tracking down the problem.

Assembling strings piecemeal in the code like that is a sucker’s game. Not only is it unnecessarily complex (with a high chance of screwing up, and printing laughably terrible messages to the user), it’s wildly inefficient (not that efficiency is a critical issue, given that you’re usually displaying these messages to the user somehow, and the time spent producing the message will be *DWARFED* by the time the user spends reading it). Plus it has other shortcomings, that I’ll get to.

Once you have the function `pluralize()`, the logical way to use it is:

```
std::cout << std::format(
    pluralize(
        count,
        "There is one file that matches the search criteria.",
        "There are {} files that match the search criteria."),
    count);
```

Even with your simple example, it looks better:

```
// std::cout << "Found " << count << " " << (count == 1 ? "file" : "files");
// std::cout << "Found " << count << " " << pluralize("file");
   std::cout << std::format(pluralize(count, "Found {} file", "Found {} files"), count);

// std::print(pluralize(count, "Found {} file", "Found {} files"), count);
// ^-- potential future C++ (P2093)
```

It’s also less complex, therefore less error-prone, and easier to optimize (in fact, with `std::format` it could *conceivably* be done at compile time). And it’s easier to search for the strings.

But the most important extra benefit is that now you have opened the door to internationalizing your program.

When you construct user interface strings in code, you make it functionally impossible to internationalize your program. You might say, “meh, I don’t care about that”… but, really? I mean, you care enough that you won’t tolerate “file(s)”. Is it that much further a leap to caring enough that people can have your program in their own language? Especially considering that it’s effectively zero extra work on your part.

Let’s imagine that you’ve written `pluralize()` as @user673679 and I suggest, and you use it in the way I suggest. So everywhere in your code where you display a message to the user that varies depending on some number, you have `pluralize(n, "singular string", "plural string")`. Let’s further imagine that your program becomes very useful, and very widely used. Naturally people will fork it and tinker with it, and probably offer you improvements. So one day, someone who speaks a different language sends you back a modified version of `pluralize()` that looks like this:

```
auto pluralize(unsigned long long n, std::string_view singular, std::string_view plural)
{
    if (auto s = string_database.lookup(singular, n); s)
        return *s;
    else if (n == 1)
        return singular;
    else
        return plural;
}
```

`string_database` is some object that holds a database of strings loaded from some file. The lookup function uses the singular string as the key, does a rapid hash or binary search, and if it finds an entry, uses some heuristics with `n` to select the proper plural. (Note that the added costs won’t really matter, because, first, you’re calling it *far* less often if you’re only calling it once per message rather than once for every word in a message that needs pluralizing, and second, you’re only using it for messages to be displayed to the user… which means the time spent searching for it will be nothing compared to the time the user spends reading it.)

Such a simple little fix. But oh, what magic results.

Because by using a database of French translations, now when a French user uses your program, they get:

- « 1 fichier trouvé » (instead of “1 file found”)
- « 3 fichiers trouvé » (instead of “3 files found”)
- « 0 fichier trouvé » (instead of “0 files found”)

A Japanese user, with a Japanese translation database, gets:

- 「1個のファイルが見つかりました」 (instead of “1 file found”)
- 「3個のファイルが見つかりました」 (instead of “3 files found”)
- 「0個のファイルが見つかりました」 (instead of “0 files found”)

I didn’t pick those examples arbitrarily. Look closer. In the Japanese, there is no difference between singular and plural. In the French, « *N* fichier trouvé » is used for 1 file ***and 0 files***. French uses the singular for any number less than 2 (so you’d say « 1,5 fichier trouvé » for “1.5 files found”, if there were such a thing as a half file). Other languages have still other quirks, like Polish:

- „Znaleziono 1 plik” (instead of “1 file found”)
- „Znaleziono 3 pliki” (instead of “3 files found”)
- „Znaleziono 0 plików” (instead of “0 files found”)

Note that the text is different for 1, 3, *and* 0. (Polish is weird.) All that complexity could be handled within the string database, so you get it for free.

You see? The magic begins when you stop trying to programmatically construct user-interface strings, and instead treat them as opaque tokens, with, at most, some replacement fields that you can pop non-translatable data into. The moment you start doing that, you open the door to internationalization. Of course, that’s only the tiniest tip of a very, very large iceberg. Internationalization is not a small topic. For a starting reference, you could read [the GNU gettext manual section about plurals](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Plural-forms). GNU gettext is a fantastic place to study the topic of formatting and internationalization of user-interface strings, but, in my humble opinion, it is possible to *massively* improve on it (especially in C++).

So I recommend you stop trying to micro-manage user-interface strings, stop trying to diddle with single singular/plural *words* (never mind *parts* of words), and instead treat entire messages as single units. It’s simpler, more efficient, and, for free, you get the possibility of future internationalization with almost no effort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a lot of information. Regarding the templates, in my usage I've found a need to occasionally support non-integer amounts (e.g. "3.3 volts"). I did think about templating the strings but the string literal for `plural_suffix` makes that difficult, so I planned to work on adding that later.

Comment: Your point about more complicated messages which require multiple calls to `pluralize` is a good one. I haven't really run into a situation where I needed it (I do deliberately phrase the message to avoid that situation), but I agree it's an issue. I wasn't aware of `std::format`, and I'm not sure which one it would be when [searching for it](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=format). Is it new to the standard? I forgot to mention in my question that I'm targeting C++14, though I'm interested in possibilities from the latest standard.

Comment: Great stuff, indi - you've made the points I was going to make (right down to using Polish as example) but explained it much better than I would.  Bravo!

Comment: The GNU gettext documentation takes a dim view of using fractional (or negative) numbers in grammatical messages, and I agree; those are used for dimensioned quantities… like you used it for: volts, the dimension of electric potential. For dimensioned quantities, you don’t need to change the text; just use the dimension’s units, like “1.0 volts” or “1.0 V”. “One-point-zero volts” is perfectly legitimate English (actually “one-point-zero volt” sounds weird). (And the gettext manual promises that the same logic applies to *all* languages.)

Comment: **BUT**, if you really wanna do it, then I would recommend having separate overloads for `long double` and `long long int` (along with `long long unsigned int`, as I proposed). (Or I guess you could also use `std::(u)intmax_t` instead of `long long (unsigned) int`. ) Reason being: that `unsigned long long int` version is still precious on its own, and should be isolated as a special case due to it being for ordinal numbers. If you want to grammaticize *non*-ordinal numbers too… well, okay, but you should still keep that ordinal case precious and distinct.

Comment: [`std::format` is C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format), and not yet widely supported. But you can use [the `{fmt}` library that it’s based on](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) with *all* versions of C++, including C++14 (though of course, with older versions of the language, you lose some features). `{fmt}` also already has `fmt::print()` (which is still only proposed as of C++23), and it’s significantly more efficient (and *much* superior in other ways) to both `std::cout` and `std::printf()`.